# LUA lib + язык C, использование функций модулей возвращает runtime error

Tags: c, lua

Использование функций стандартных модулей Lua постоянно возвращает Runtime error. Пример кода:

```
//...
char script[] = "io.write(\"Hello!\n\")";
printf("%d\n", luaL_loadbuffer(L, script, strlen(script), NULL));
printf("%d\n", lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0));
//...
```

На экран выводит:

```
0
2
```

Согласно определению ошибок в lua.h, числу 2 соответствует LUA_ERRRUN.

При этом в терминале эта же самая строка работает:

```
$ lua
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> io.write("Hello!\n");
Hello!
```

Использование стандартных элементов lua не приводит к ошибке:

```
//...
char script[] = "print(\"Hello!\")";
printf("%d\n", luaL_loadbuffer(L, script, strlen(script), NULL));
printf("%d\n", lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0));
//...
```

Выводит:

```
0
Hello!
0
```

Как правильно использовать такие функции?
Спасибо!

Comment: Стандартные библиотеки загружены?

Comment: @val Дело в том, что на загрузку этих стандартных библиотек он выдаёт ту же самую ошибку. Например, если я напишу "local myLib = require "io", то он крашнется на этой строке.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы получить сообщение об ошибке в читаемом виде, можно пользоваться функцией `lua_tostring` и для вашего примера она должна сообщить:

```
[string "io.write("Hello!..."]:1: unfinished string near '"Hello!'
```

Это сообщение говорит о том, что `Lua` на своей стороне обнаружила незавершённую строку.

Дело в том, что Си, перед тем, как передать строку куда либо, преобразует управляющий символ `\n` в перевод строки и на стороне `Lua` код получается таким:

```
io.write("Hello!
")
```

Что является синтаксически не верной конструкцией.

Чтобы избежать этой ошибки, нужно сделать так, чтобы Си не вмешивался и не портил строку. Делается это двойным экранированием управляющего символа: `\\n`.

Вот, что в итоге должно получиться:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>

int main (void) {

  char script[] = "io.write(\"Hello!\\n\")";

  lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();   /* открывает Lua */
  luaL_openlibs(L);                 /* открывает стандартные библиотеки */

  int error = luaL_loadstring(L, script) || lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);

  if (error) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
    lua_pop(L, 1);  /* снять сообщение об ошибке со стека */
  }

  lua_close(L);  /* закрывает Lua */

  return 0;
}
```

Если бы вы загружали скрипт из файла, то такой ошибки не возникло бы и там никакого двойного экраниования, естественно, делать не нужно.

И напоследок, если бы вы правильно обработали ошибку, как это сделано в примере выше, то нагуглить решение по тексту ошибки, не составило бы труда.

Comment: Отличный ответ! Спасибо! Последнее замечание особенно понравилось!